# Measuring traffic caused by a (part of a) python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, networking

I am currently writing a performance test for a system that I built. I am executing X thousand API calls and measuring the time it takes. I would now also like to know how much traffic the X thousand calls caused. However, I am running the test 30 times inside a loop so that I can calculate the mean and the confidence intervals to filter out spikes because of overflowing buffers and such. Is there a tool that allows me to calculate the traffic caused by my script for each loop?

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958614/measure-network-data-with-python) suggests to use psutil, however that seems to measure the network traffic for the whole system?

Comment: are you using the Requests module?

Comment: Nope, I am using http.client

Comment: If you can switch to using it, I recommend [checking this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064891/python-requests-urllib-monitoring-bandwidth-usage). Otherwise I'm not aware of a way to do this (but there are lots of things I'm not aware of).

Comment: I will look into it, thank you for the suggestion :)